# SharePoint 2010 People Search is slow

Tags: people-search, sharepoint-search

We are using SharePoint 2010 enterprise Search and we are experience a performance issue when users do people search.

1. Users go to the search box and search for a user, for example: **Jason**, and get the results **without any issues.**
2. When users do the same search and type in: **Jason G** it takes over 2 min to get the results.
3. Users search for: **Jason Gi** they get the result within 3 seconds.

I ran FireBug while searching for **Jason G** and saw the following errors while waiting for the results:

[image]

Once I get the results, I get the following message in FireBug

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Go to internet explorer>tools>internet options> connections> Lan settings> then turn off "automatically detect settings".

Worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it did not work for me.

Comment: check your users permissions. try the search under a sca (site collection administrator) and see if the search speeds up

Comment: No go. It has nothing to do with permission. The issue happens when we do people search using a single character for the second term: John D, it works when we use John Do. We created a new site collection based on Search center template and we get an error. I created a new post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111989/people-search-error-internal-server-error-exception-system-threading-threadabor?noredirect=1#comment110949_111989