# People Search error Internal server error exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

We are using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise search center and we are getting an error when we do people search, for example **John D** (Note: we don't get the error if we use: **John Do** or **John Doe**)
Error:

> Internal server error exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformSelect() 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DataBind() 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.EnsureDataBound() 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
>      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchResultsBaseWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
>      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.CreateChildControls()
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: a762b520-9cfb-4018-bd56-14abcdd00a58

Again **ONLY** when we search for people in the following format: John D (one letter after the first term).

We do different farms and we are experiencing the same behavior.

Here is ULS log based on the correlation Id:

```
08/14/2014 16:52:09.55  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://servername.local:80/sites/esearchcenter/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k=yassar%20a) f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.57  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/esearchcenter   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.57  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=12.4286745941174   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.60  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  Web Content Management  Publishing  7fz3    Medium  Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.60  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Portal Server    Web Parts   dn2u    Medium  SearchBoxEx AfterDeserialize begin  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    

08/14/2014 16:52:09.60  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Portal Server    Web Parts   dn2w    Medium  SearchBoxEx AfterDeserialize end    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.61  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn4s    High    FetchDataFromURL start at(outside if): 1 param: start   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.61  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka1    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetUserPreferenceSerializeHelper--Proxy Name:esearchSearchProxy EndPoint: http://servername.local:32843/ccdf5a9e13324d9f81b8039a9575488d/SearchService.svc   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.61  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk8z    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--Channel Creation time: 0 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.61  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://servername.local:32843/ccdf5a9e13324d9f81b8039a9575488d/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/ISearchSiteAdministrationServiceApplication/GetUserPreferenceSerializeHelper' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:f081afbc-bade-4683-860f-0efc7d573d51'   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka2    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetUserPreferenceSerializeHelper--Id: Elapsed Time: 15.6251 Proxy Name/ID: esearchSearchProxy/f40ff4aa-6d1d-4e6f-b95b-252d0e16daeb EndPoint: http://servername.local:32843/ccdf5a9e13324d9f81b8039a9575488d/SearchService.svc    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category MaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  Web Content Management  Publishing  7fz3    Medium  Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.63  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  Web Content Management  Publishing  7fz3    Medium  Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.65  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  fx8a    Medium  SearcherInfo::Deserialize - Deserialization failed because hash values don't match. f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.65  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://server.local:32843/a29b077204fb4e9ab264c6967ffbd020/ProfileDBCacheService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfileDBCacheService' Action: 'http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetUserData' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:09af6c2c-368d-4ef6-9002-ca838de8ce0e'   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.66  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka1    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Proxy Name:esearchSearchProxy EndPoint: http://servername.local:32843/ccdf5a9e13324d9f81b8039a9575488d/SearchService.svc    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.66  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk8z    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--Channel Creation time: 0 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.66  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://servername.local:32843/ccdf5a9e13324d9f81b8039a9575488d/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication/Execute' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:adadc808-d936-48c2-b3ff-79593a6ec4d2' f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mb    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://servername.local:32843/ccdf5a9e13324d9f81b8039a9575488d/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication/Execute' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:adadc808-d936-48c2-b3ff-79593a6ec4d2'   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Server Search    Query   fla3    High    SearchServiceApplication::Execute--Correlation Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    08/14/2014 16:52:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Server Search    Query Processor dm6f    Medium  PluggableSecurityTrimmerManager:SetSearchApplicationToUse: Set SearchApplication to 'esearchSearch' f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:52:09.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Server Search    Query Processor dm22    Medium  Resetting cookie: Old value = '', new value = 'yassar a*RankDescending' f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Server Search    Exceptions  1hjo    Medium  Exception thrown: 0x80040e31 (d:\office\source\search\native\ytrip\tripoli\icommand\qryspec.cxx:1056 ip 0x000007FEE53D8E81) f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Server Search    Query Processor e2o1    High    In CRootQuerySpec::Execute - caught exception: 0x80040e31, translated to: 0x80040e31    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  0000    High    Log Query: More Information: Execution stopped because a resource limit was reached. No results were returned.  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk68    High    SearchServiceApplication::Execute--Exception: System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: System error. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties)   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x1314)   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=89999.8773587146    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication/Execute). Execution Time=90014.6437605897    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (Execute). Execution Time=90016.0492464824  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   ele3    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault]: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault).   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (SharePointSearchRuntime::GetQueryResult). Execution Time=90031.8694135707  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlr1    High    Exception when fetching results: System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: System error. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowBackwardCompatibleException(FaultException`1 ex) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRuntime.GetQueryResult(String query) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRuntime.SendRequest(String query)   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (SharePointSearchRuntime::SendRequest). Execution Time=90032.5946454088 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.68  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (RefinementManager.GetRefinementXml()). Execution Time=90037.2589253662 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.69  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (DataBinding DataFormWebPart (People Refinement Panel)). Execution Time=90038.9373509762    f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.69  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (People Refinement Panel CreateChildControls). Execution Time=90039.1535795751  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.69  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   g1j9    Exception   Internal server error exception: System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: System error. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowBackwardCompatibleException(FaultException`1 ex) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRuntime.GetQueryResult(String query) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRuntime.SendRequest(String query) System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: System error. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowBackwardCompatibleException(FaultException`1 ex) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRuntime.GetQueryResult(String query) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRuntime.SendRequest(String query)   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.69  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server   Unified Logging Service c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 06175311 "sharepoint server search", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", 17853a8f "microsoft.office.server.search", 0e0017eb "14.0.6123.0", 4fcf540b "wed jun 06 06:58:51 2012", 00001af9 "00001af9", 00000097 "00000097", e19bc27f "timeoutexception", 67316a39 "g1j9"   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.71  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server   General 7888    Warning A runtime exception was detected. Details follow.  Message: Thread was being aborted.  Technical Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() 
    at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryUIError.GetErrorMessageOrRedirectToErrorPage(Exception ex, Boolean showMessages) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsDatasourceView.GetXmlResponseDoc(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath) f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.71  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   g1j9    Exception   (Watson Reporting Cancelled) System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() 
    at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryUIError.GetErrorMessageOrRedirectToErrorPage(Exception ex, Boolean showMessages) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsDatasourceView.GetXmlResponseDoc(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath) f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.83  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (People Search Core Results GetXPathNavigator). Execution Time=148.309910896497 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.83  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1b    High    PeopleCoreResultsWebPart: Exception was thrown System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() 
    at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryUIError.GetErrorMessageOrRedirectToErrorPage(Exception ex, Boolean showMessages) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.PeopleCoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath)   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.85  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (People Search Core Results GetXPathNavigator). Execution Time=152.177720911457 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.85  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Web Parts   89a1    High    Error while executing web part: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at System.Globalization.TextInfo.nativeChangeCaseString(Int32 win32LangID, Void* pNativeTextInfo, String str, Boolean isToUpper) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.Utility.IsLayoutsRequest() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DfwpCacheRead(Storage storage, String key, Boolean forceSharedAppCache) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXslCompiledTransform() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.85  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (DataBinding DataFormWebPart (People Search Core Results)). Execution Time=156.617391316494 f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.85  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server   General 7888    Warning A runtime exception was detected. Details follow.  Message: Thread was being aborted.  Technical Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformSelect() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DataBind() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.EnsureDataBound() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchResultsBaseWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.CreateChildControls()  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:39.85  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Server Search    Query   g1j9    Exception   (Watson Reporting Cancelled) System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformSelect() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DataBind() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.EnsureDataBound() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchResultsBaseWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.CreateChildControls()  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:40.01  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (People Search Core Results CreateChildControls). Execution Time=315.648776590321   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
    08/14/2014 16:53:40.01  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  Web Content Management  Publishing  7fov    Medium  Caught a thread abort exception in TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest, the exception may be expected. stack trace=   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at ASP.PEOPLESEARCHRESULTS_ASPX_917408415.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84    
08/14/2014 16:53:40.01  w3wp.exe (0x10FC)   0x0668  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://servername.local:80/sites/esearchcenter/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k=yassar%20a)). Execution Time=90460.4004140191   f5393503-05c8-4427-ae6f-c4ed61a4ff84
```

Comment: Could you give all the information from the ULS?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this type of error, it is really great if you give us the complete trace of ULS logs. to get complete trace just run the below script accoridng to your locations.

```
Merge-SPLogFile –Path “S:\SPLogs\MergedLogs.log” –Correlation "GUID"
```

Couple of things to make sure.

- People Crawl is completed, may be try to run full People crawl
- User Profile Services is up and running,
- User Profile Sync is running
- Reset IIS
- Look at the query string in the failed URL. If you convert the %20s to %22s do you get a result

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6bf012d5-2ace-4375-9017-a7277ae60f36/people-search-error?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did check the listed items and also followed the technet link and that did not help.

Comment: did you change the query string?

Answer (score 1):

"The thread was being aborted" is, next to the null reference exception, the most frustrating of all SharePoint errors. Usually it means something timed out on the back end, and the timing on your ULS logs (that you're getting that after a full minute) seems to point to the same.

Otherwise, are you running custom code? If so, maybe try putting in some more detailed logging to figure out exactly where things are breaking? If it's OOB Enterprise search, what happens if you turn People search off entirely?